# SQL Server 2012: DATETIME discrepancies between inserts and triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

We are having a very strange problem whereby when calling `GETUTCDATE()` the returned value is very slightly earlier in the second statement than the first. The scenario we have is the following:

1. We insert into a table to track a users current status, this table has a trigger on which inserts into an associated history table of the users past statuses with a `DATETIME` field and the insert calls `GETUTCDATE()`
2. Once this is done we have another table with an associated record we insert into calling `GETUTCDATE()` which tracks which part updated the user status.

So the flow would be:

1. Insert into `UserStatuses`
2. Trigger fires on `UserStatuses` table inserting into `UserStatusesHistory` calling `GETUTCDATE()`
3. Then we insert into `OwningStatuses` table calling `GETUTCDATE()`

We are finding that on some occasions the `DATETIME` on the `UserStatusesHistory` is after the `DATETIME` on the `OwningStatuses` table.

How can this be when the `GETUTCDATE()` on the `OwningStatuses` is called after the `GETUTCDATE()` for the `UserStatusesHistory` table?

In some scenarios are triggers run asynchronously? (I can't believe this as it's against everything I have read and we are not using any service brokers).

Is it possible the `GETUTCDATE()` is cached at the beginning of the procedure on some occasions and this cached value isn't carried into the trigger?

Comment: Possible duplicate or similar to this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036223/will-getutcdate-return-the-same-value-if-used-twice-in-the-same-statement

Comment: @JamiePollard Doesn't look like a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the declarative nature of SQL, the database engine *might* take the liberty to evaluate parts of a SQL statement in any order it sees fit (as long as it doesn't affect semantics). Your suggestion that `GETUTCDATE()` might be cached, is a plausible one.

I know this does not answer your question. But whatever the implementation of GETUTCDATE in SQL2012, it might well change in a future version. So avoid relying on it, or future upgrades could become a real pain. Implement your logic in a way that does not rely on any assumptions regarding evaluation order.

In your specific case, I see a few possible solutions.

1. If you have no problem with `OwningStatuses` having a time slightly *later* than `UserStatusesHistory`, then it might already help if you send the third step off to SQL Server as a separate batch.
2. Swap steps 2 and 3; and let the trigger query `OwningStatuses` instead of making up its own date.
3. Stop using triggers; there is more than one reason to consider this.

Answer (score 0):

The hardware / OS clock was adjusted between the calls. Happenss.

You want cached values - you have to reprogram all access to set a variable first, then use that value in subsequent calls ;(